Overlaying spots on the image of spatial transcriptomics in python
I am doing spatial transcriptomics analysis of triple negative breast cancer. I am having issue when I overlay my spots on my image. It gives me totally right spots on a plot but when I try to embed them on the image it does not fit on the image. I have tried many ways but facing the same issue.
my spots image

with the embedded image.

I tried everything I gave the tissue hires image and made anndata that gives me the exact spots. But it is not embedding the spot on the image
